# How to calculate the operability ratio per month on Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe containing start & end dates of available slots (called 'operability_df_x' in the code):

[image]

I'm trying to calculate how many hours are available per month, let's call it the operability ratio. The output is the following (called 'g' in the code):

[image]

The current code I wrote is the following, however since I'm new to pandas & python I get the impression there is a lot of redundancy. Is there an easier way to achieve my goal directly without writing 30 lines of code ? Thanks in advance for any piece of advice

```
for i in operability_df_x.index :
        a = operability_df_x['Start Date'].loc[i].month
        b = operability_df_x['Start Date'].loc[i].year
        c = datetime.datetime(b,a+1,1,0,0,0)
        #  The following condition is in case there is an interval that stretches in two months :
        window = chain_seq_glob[(chain_seq_glob['Start Date'] < c) & (chain_seq_glob['End Date'] > c)].reset_index(drop=True)
        if not window.empty :
            if (operability_df_x.iloc[i].equals(window.iloc[0])):            
                operability_df_x['End Date'].loc[i] = c            
                window['Start Date'].loc[0] = c            
                operability_df_x = operability_df_x.append(window)           
    

    operability_df_x['Duration [Hours]'] = (operability_df_x['End Date'] - operability_df_x['Start Date'] ) / pd.to_timedelta(1, unit ='h')     
    operability_df_x = operability_df_x[['Start Date','End Date', 'Duration [Hours]']]
    operability_df_x = operability_df_x.sort_values(by="Start Date").reset_index(drop=True)
    operability_df_x.to_csv('Operab.csv')
    ### Final operability table:
    g = operability_df_x.set_index('Start Date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).sum().reset_index(drop=False)
    g['Year/Month'] = g['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
    g = g.reindex(columns=['Year/Month','Duration [Hours]','Start Date'])
    g.columns = ['Year/Month','Total Available Hours','End month']
    
    g['Total Monthly Hours'] = (g['End month'].apply(lambda x: int(x.strftime('%d'))))*24
    g['Operability ratio'] = g['Total Available Hours'] / g['Total Monthly Hours']
    g = g.drop(['End month','Total Monthly Hours'], 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider an example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start': pd.to_datetime(['20200103', '20200104', '20200123', '20200205']),
    'end': pd.to_datetime(['20200105', '20200107', '20200203', '20200209']),
})
```

Let's also define a utility function:

```py
def intervals(row):
    if row.start.month == row.end.month:
        return [(row.start, row.end)]
    middle = row.end.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
    return [(row.start, middle), (middle, row.end)]
```

Now, let's use it to get a list of intervals (either one or two) for each row depending on how many months the row spans:

```py
df['intervals'] = df.apply(intervals, axis=1)
```

Now, let's explode this list so that each interval has a row of its own:

```py
df = df.explode('intervals')['intervals']
df = pd.DataFrame(df.tolist(), columns=['start', 'end'])
```

Let's add a column we'll use later for grouping:

```py
df['month'] = df['start'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

And one for the number of hours between `start` and `end`:

```py
df['hours'] = (df['end'] - df['start']).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

I'm sure there is a better way to get the total number of hours for a given month. I'm doing it by adding two separate columns for the beginning of the current month and the beginning of the next month. Then, I add yet another column to store the difference between the two:

```py
df['month_start'] = df['start'].apply(
  lambda d: d.replace(day=1, hour=0, second=0))
df['month_end'] = df['month_start'].apply(
  lambda d: d.replace(month=(d.month+1) % 12, year=d.year + int(d.month==12)))
df['total_hours'] = (df['month_end'] - df['month_start']).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

Finally, perform the group-by and aggregate:

```py
df = df.groupby('month').agg({'hours': 'sum', 'total_hours': 'first'})
df['ratio'] = df['hours'] / df['total_hours']
```

There are lots of built-in utility functions for dates I am not familiar with so I'm sure some of the stages could be substituted for an idiomatic expression but this works and is quite readable.

Comment: First of all, thanks for this quick reply. For the example you proposed, I intend on counting '2 minutes' in March & '1hours 20 min' in April. That's what my first for-loop does, it checks exceptions where (Start < 'Month_X' and End > 'Month_X') after that I reindex my dataframe and calculate the ratio by grouping & aggregating

Comment: I would love to see your way of coding in order to solve this, if you have time of course

Comment: And how is the number of sequences supposed to be split between the new rows generated from one row?

Comment: You can ignore the column 'number of sequences', it was useful for another purpose. What I share is a portion of a big project, so the number of sequences is irrelevant for the operability ratio part

Comment: Unless I didn't understand your question correctly

Comment: ok, great - one more question - do you need to deal with rows that span over more than two months or can we assume that this can never happen?

Comment: Well if a row spans over two months, we shall consider that the operability ratio == 1 for each full month

Comment: Good eye from your part, because in my code I neglected this case. It can mess up the ratios

Comment: I've just seen the edit, the job was marvelously done ! I didn't knew we could use new defined methods in '.apply()' that can come in handy. Also, the 'explode()' part was creative. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is one small problem though, when you grouped & aggregated you summed the total hours for each month too. The more rows you add the more total hours of a month goes to infinity x) But it's easily fixable

Comment: Good catch, I updated the answer with a fix